# how to take a hash and turn into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to take the following:

```
{"6"=>"", "7"=>"104", "8"=>"", "9"=>"", "0"=>"Testing", "2"=>"1", "3"=>"", "10"=>"Testing", "4"=>"1", "5"=>""}
```

and convert it into

```
[["","104","","","Testing"........], ["" ......]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hash class has the method `values` which returns an array of all the values.

```
my_hash = {"6" => "", "7" => "104"}
my_array_of_values = my_hash.values # ["", "104"]
```

In Ruby, the Hash contains key/value pairs (eg. { key => value }).  The `keys` method returns an array of the keys and the `values` method returns an array of the values.

Read more about the values method here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002867